# Uploading a csv file to separate parquet files based on 2 column data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, parquet

I have a csv file like shown below.

[image]

I want to filter the distinct values of ID and Combinations and save each combo as a parquet file. example : 12888_1.parquet, 13368_1.parquet etc.... I have several different IDs and 6 combinations [1,2,3,4,5,6].

I am aware that copy activity can save any file as .parquet file with a custom name, But I am not sure how to grouping the column and saving the parquet files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- You can achieve your requirement using the combination of dataflows and pipeline activities. Use a dataflow activity to get the unique `id+combination` values using aggregate transformation, use sink cache, iterate through this result and pass the values to another dataflow to filter and write based on these values.
- The following is a sample file data that I have taken:

```
id,combo,character
123,1,A
123,1,B
123,1,C
234,1,D
234,1,E
234,2,F
234,2,G
234,2,H
234,2,I
234,3,J
345,3,K
345,3,L
345,3,M
456,4,N
456,4,O
567,5,P
567,5,Q
567,6,R
678,6,S
```

- Now, I have taken this as my dataflow source. I have added an aggregate transformation and grouped the data by `id and combo`. Use any aggregate transformation (we will exclude this in mapping anyway).

[image]

- Now, select only the id and combo and use sink cache. The following is how the debug output of the dataflow activity looks like:

[image]

- Now iterate through this using for each activity with the following dynamic content:

```
@activity('get unique id and combo').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value
```

- Pass the values of id and combo in each iteration to the new dataflow. The following is an image of the same:

[image]

- In the new dataflow, take the required file as source. Use filter activity with the following condition:

```
id==$id && combo==$combo
```

[image]

- Use the following dynamic content and configuration to name the file for each iteration:

```
concat($id,'_',$combo,'.parquet')
```

[image]

- The following is how the files will be written to your storage account as parquet files:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show me your 'get unique id and combo' aggregate and group by options and for some reason I am not able to process more than 1 combination.